# Periodic Points in Julia Set under Rational Map

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, rational-functions, fractals

Let $A_1$ be the finite set of periodic points in the Julia set for a rational map, $R$, which has lowest possible period.

Inductively, define $A_{n+1} = R^{-1} (A_n) \cup A_n$.

Why is it true that $A_n$ is finite for all $n$?

For context, I am looking at Sullivan's proof to the No Wandering Domain Theorem ([https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math627.S13/Sullivan-1985-Nonwandering.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math627.S13/Sullivan-1985-Nonwandering.pdf)) on page 410.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The $A_n$ are all root sets of polynomials, so finite by construction. Is that sufficient as reason?

Comment: But does the number of solutions not get arbitrarily large as n approaches infinity? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, but that was not the claim in the question. The claim is that for each individual $n$ the set $A_n$ is finite. Should that not be the case, then please "sharpen" the question.